# String join on strings in Vec in reverse order without a `collect`

Tags: string, iterator, rust

I'm trying to join strings in a vector into a single string, in reverse from their order in the vector. The following works:

```
let v = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()];
v.iter().rev().map(|s| s.clone()).collect::<Vec<String>>().connect(".")
```

However, this ends up creating a temporary vector that I don't actually need. Is it possible to do this without a `collect`? I see that `connect` is a `StrVector` method. Is there nothing for raw iterators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an iterator extension trait that I whipped up, just for you!

```
pub trait InterleaveExt: Iterator + Sized {
    fn interleave(self, value: Self::Item) -> Interleave<Self> {
        Interleave {
            iter: self.peekable(),
            value: value,
            me_next: false,
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> InterleaveExt for I {}

pub struct Interleave<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    iter: std::iter::Peekable<I>,
    value: I::Item,
    me_next: bool,
}

impl<I> Iterator for Interleave<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: Clone,
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // Don't return a value if there's no next item
        if let None = self.iter.peek() {
            return None;
        }

        let next = if self.me_next {
            Some(self.value.clone())
        } else {
            self.iter.next()
        };

        self.me_next = !self.me_next;
        next
    }
}
```

It can be called like so:

```
fn main() {
    let a = &["a", "b", "c"];
    let s: String = a.iter().cloned().rev().interleave(".").collect();
    println!("{}", s);

    let v = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()];
    let s: String = v.iter().map(|s| s.as_str()).rev().interleave(".").collect();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

I've since learned that this iterator adapter already exists in itertools under the name [`intersperse`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.5.9/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.intersperse) — go use that instead!.

#### Cheating answer

You never said you *needed* the original vector after this, so we can reverse it in place and just use `join`...

```
let mut v = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()];
v.reverse();
println!("{}", v.join("."))
```

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is the shortest you can get:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()];
    let mut r = v.iter()
        .rev()
        .fold(String::new(), |r, c| r + c.as_str() + ".");
    r.pop();
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

The addition operation on `String` takes its left operand by value and pushes the second operand in-place, which is very nice - it does not cause any reallocations. You don't even need to `clone()` the contained strings.

I think, however, that the lack of `concat()`/`connect()` methods on iterators is a serious drawback. It bit me a lot too.

Comment: Do you know if there's been discussion about implementing those methods for iterators before? Is it not done because it's tricky or because no one's got around to it?

Comment: @Ray, it is most certainly that no one's got around to it. I'm not aware of any discussions, and for some reason (laziness, most probably :() I didn't start any myself.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if they've heard our Stack Overflow prayers or what, but the [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate happens to have just the method you need - [`join`](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/fn.join.html).

With it, your example might be laid out as follows:

```
use itertools::Itertools;
let v = ["a", "b", "c"];
let connected = v.iter().rev().join(".");
```